# "F is the vector space of functions defined in R with real variables. Is the subset of funtions of which f(1)=0 a subspace of F?"

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I don't even really understand the question to begin with and not exactly what I have to I desperately need help haha!

"F is the vector space of functions defined in R with real variables. Is the subset of funtions of which f(1)=0 a subspace of F?"

Comment: Do you know the characterization of a linear subspace? What does $F$ need to satisfy to be a subspace? It is certainly a subset.

Comment: Yes I do have a list of I think 10 characteristics. And I think that for determining if a subset is a subspace you need to show that it is non-empty, addition should have closure, and multiplication by a scalar that I don't understand. Also I would like to mention that I don't have a book on this so I can't just 'look it up'

Comment: You can definitely do a quick google search of "subspace"; for instance the Wikipedia page will have sufficient information on this. But yes, you need to show: $0\in F$, that $F$ is closed under addition, and the third is that $F$ is closed under scalar multiplication (i.e. if you take $f\in F$ and some real number $c$, is $cf\in F$?).

Comment: Ok thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subset of such functions is closed under addition (if $f(1)=g(1)=0$ then $[f+g](1)=f(1)+g(1)=0$) and multiplication by a scalar (if $f(1)=0$ then $[\lambda f](1)=\lambda f(1)=0$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$).

Hence it is a subspace by definition.